# Uboot custom application images load from flash

Tags: u-boot

I have 2 images stored in predefined addresses in flash that are loaded based on some criteria I can test for on bootup.

Can someone please suggest a method to programmatically launch either image using uboot's tools like bootm, etc? Or point to an example of this procedure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume whatever method you use to load the images takes an address, so just set that before running it.  `bootcmd` is the main entry point, `boot` is basically the same as `run bootcmd`.

```
setenv flashload 'fooload $imageflashaddr $loadaddr'
setenv setimageflashaddr 'if something; then setenv imageflashaddr xxx ; else setenv imageflashaddr yyy; fi'
setenv bootcmd 'run setimageflashaddr && run flashload && bootm $loadaddr'
```

u-boot is enormously flexible; there are many ways to do this.  This uses environment variables.  You can also do this from C code or from a script file you load at run time.

---

If you want to do it in C code, you can edit your board's C file (usually in `board/vendor_name/board_name.c`.  You can define a `board_late_init()` (there are other hooks, but this one is usually a good place to start).  You can use `env_get()` and `env_set()` to set your address so your bootcmd loads from different places.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I’d ike to use the C code approach instead of the env vars. Is there an example? I’m using an SPL build.